# Angular - Providing asynchronous to root providers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-dependency-injection

My goal is to load a configuration file (from assets) which includes settings I need for my http service.
Currently I have an `APP_INITIALIZER` service which loads the file and sets it in the service properties. 
Thing is, the http service is `providedIn: 'root'` and Angular constructs it before the config is loaded which results in getting an `undefined` when trying to access the "saved" config.

How can I make sure the config will be loaded before those services are constructed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the 3rd method posted here:

https://netbasal.com/optimize-user-experience-while-your-angular-app-loads-7e982a67ff1a